# How can I plot different file in a single plot?

Tags: r, file, plot, statistics, read.table

I'm working on R 3.1.1 GUI 1.65 Mavericks build (6784) and I would like to say that I have 3 textual files (file1, file2, file3) which exactly have these format:

```
-6.302229035036262 -20.0 -1.020941553137966 
-4.04318422254186 -3.583695163352756 -3.6530481033374245 
-2.077324334243253 -20.0 -20.0 
-6.302229035036262 -20.0 -1.020941553137966 
-6.4977283774856875 -10.964877298563136 -1.1022927689594357 
-6.291583374531307 -16.450926383021542 -1.176625625964833 
-6.223879288477839 -12.115100317368787 -1.5212364609954971
```

The separator is a blank space, there are not neither column names nor row names, and what is crucial is that the last character is an other blank space separator (" "). Unfortunately the last separator of the row is unremovable since those files are previously generated by an external software.

Here are my steps:
1) I set my working directory where files are located

```
setwd(“working directory”)
```

2) I create a matrix from a file (Note that I'm using read.csv even if it has no extension even though it's readable from any kind of editor)
I finally save it in a variable

```
data <- as.matrix(read.csv(“file1″, header=FALSE, sep=” “));
```

A new [Nx4] matrix is created where R interpret as:

```
            V1         V2         V3 V4
[1,] -6.302229 -20.000000  -1.020942 NA
[2,] -4.043184  -3.583695  -3.653048 NA
[3,] -2.077324 -20.000000 -20.000000 NA
[4,] -6.302229 -20.000000  -1.020942 NA
[5,] -6.497728 -10.964877  -1.102293 NA
[6,] -6.291583 -16.450926  -1.176626 NA
[7,] -6.223879 -12.115100  -1.521236 NA
```

The problem now is that I would like to have an Nx3 matrix instead of Nx4, and that problem is caused by the last blank separator. How can I tell R to interpret that the last character/separator should be removed? I would like to get something like this as a result:

```
            V1         V2         V3
[1,] -6.302229 -20.000000  -1.020942
[2,] -4.043184  -3.583695  -3.653048
[3,] -2.077324 -20.000000 -20.000000
[4,] -6.302229 -20.000000  -1.020942
[5,] -6.497728 -10.964877  -1.102293
[6,] -6.291583 -16.450926  -1.176626
[7,] -6.223879 -12.115100  -1.521236
```

At that time, I don't know how to plot it in order to change column name with for example: f1, f2 and f3.

Having done the plot, I would like to plot the other 2 files in the same plot, thus the final plot could contain 3 different output.

Thank you all for collaboration.

Comment: Individual questions usually work best, not (1) remove (or ignore) a column, (2) plot it (3) change the column names (4) plot multiple files in the same plot. You seem to have a very good grasp of the individual steps you need to do, which is good. I'm skeptical you've done much searching for help for many of them, like renaming columns or removing a single column.

Comment: Simply because I thought that exists a single line command to do that instead of doing them separately, I mean something I have done with data <- as.matrix(read.csv(“file1″, header=FALSE, sep=” “)); where in a signle line I read a file with specific properties, than switch it in a matrix and saved in a variable. I know that renaming columns is done by colnames(data) = c("name1", "name2" etc.). But ok, if I'm wrong I apologize for that... Anyway, plotting them together is what I would really like to see, and if you know how to do that I will appreciate it. Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 0):

To drop column just rewrite the variable without the column:

```
data = data[,-4]
```

or

```
data = data[,colnames(data) != "V4"]
```

Depends what works in your case.

to rename use:

```
colnames(data) = c("colname1","colname2","colname3","colname4")
```

To plot multiple things on the same plot. For the first series use plot(), for the following ones use lines() or points() functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but since I have a Nx3 matrix passing it as a variable in the plot() command doesn't work as expected, because it shows me just a 2D chart. I have done it with plot(data)

Comment: Plot it column by column - one column per plot.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do it? Plot (f1) plot (f2) and plot (f3)? Are they followed by hold on function? Because it doesn't weirdly find that package. Are you sure that plotting step by step is going to change the chart's dimensions from 1D to 3D?

Comment: plot(data[,1], t="l");
lines(data[,2])

Comment: Please use "help(plot)"